# How can I drag my box made with \rule

Tags: boxes, geometry, rules

First of all english isn't my first language so it may sound weird. I made a box with the help of a question asked by someone else and it won't go acrossed the whole document.

the code I used is
`\newcommand\crude[3][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}`
and
`\crude[red!22!green!45!blue!73!]{21cm}{1cm}`

and this may be the cause of the Problem but I also used
`\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}`

can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Thenwe do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Try  `\noindent\crude[red!22!green!45!blue!73!]{\textwidth}{1cm}` (horizontal rule)  or  `\noindent\crude[red!22!green!45!blue!73!]{1cm}{\textheight}` (vertical rule)